# How to fix when I can't create laravel project? error: In CurlDownloader.php line 372:

Tags: laravel-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxAjB.png)I have a problem while creating laravel project.
I use command "composer create-project laravel/laravel reward_system" Then I get the error like this"In CurlDownloader.php line 372:

curl error 35 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legac
y renegotiation disabled

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [ [ []]]"

I try to fix but still not ok. so could annyone can help me?

I try to fix but still not ok. I need to create new laravel project but I can't create becase it's error like I mentions above.

Comment: Searching for your error turns up some answers, have you tried those? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714254/site-works-on-chrome-but-not-on-curl, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603314/ssl-error-unsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75763525/curl-35-error0a000152ssl-routinesunsafe-legacy-renegotiation-disabled, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083569/curl-error-cannot-connect-ssl-is-disabled-error-number-35, ...

Answer (score 0):

In laravel-8+ use..

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel reward_system 8.*
```

to create new project.

As you can see in the error *[-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-dist]*, so add **--prefer-dist**

## Edit

Additional setup.

1.Temporary disable the **IPv6** in Network.

[image]

2. Setup the **IPv4** with the below config.
   [image]

on CMD.

> php artisan config:clear

> php artisan optimize:clear

Then re-
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel reward_system 8.*`

Comment: I try but still not success it still error.

Comment: what error? can you post the error message? Make sure you follow the procedure in creating a project - *Like run ```CMD>cd desktop>composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel reward_system 8.*``` .* make sure your running internet w/o proxy or if have *set hittp proxy* before *composer create*.

Comment: In the comment section I can't find the button upload image teacher.

Comment: I edit my answer please check if it solve the problem.

Comment: I follow you but still not ok. I don't know why.